# Need to upload APK to browserstack that is over 15mb

Tags: curl, browserstack

I need to upload an .apk file to browserstack, but it won't load, as it is too large. I tried to create a url for it with curl, but this was my result:

Warning: Illegally formatted input field!
curl: option -F: is badly used here
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

I also uploaded my apk to dropbox and attempted to share it that way through a url, but that did not work either.

If anyone could help me, that would be great!

I ran both

```
curl -u "YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_ACCESS_KEY" \
-X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload" \
-F "file=@/path/to/app/file/Application-debug.apk" \
-F "custom_id=CalculatorApp"
```

and
curl -u "YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_ACCESS_KEY" 
-X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload" 
-F "file=@/path/to/app/file/application-debug.apk"
but neither worked.
I also encounter an error message on the browserstack website anytime I try to upload the apk.

Answer (score 2):

/path/to/app/file/Application-debug.apk is not the path to your application. It should be /Users/matchstik/src/file.apk depending on where your file lives.

You can use `pwd` in terminal to find the location of your file once you are in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

The App size is not an issue here as Browserstack supports apps up to the size of 1GB.

Based on the error message it seems that the file path specified is incorrect.

If you are using the free trial version to test the app and have exhausted the limit on one of your accounts ideally the app upload would not be supported from another account.

If you can let me know the error you are getting on the dashboard that would out be in a better position to comment about the same.

Thanks.